# Pass an __init__ value from a higher class into a subclass requiring that same argument

Tags: python, class

I am creating a small game that creates a tower.

The tower has two components, the base and the gun. In order to do so I am trying to pass the value of `self.x` into the `__init__` function of a subclass. I will further add an `update()` function once I have a solution.

Here is my code. (Poorly formatted and incomplete... sorry!)

```
import pygame
from math import atan2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption('Foongus v0.1')
pygame.init()

class home_base:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        class base:
            def __init__(self, x, y):
                self.image = pygame.image.load('base.png')
                screen.blit(self.image, (x, y))
        class gun:
            def __init__(self, x, y):
                self.image = pygame.image.load('gun.png')
                screen.blit(self.image, (x, y))

home = home_base(300, 300)
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Its not exactly clear in your example as to where you are trying to pass the value into the sub class, can you clarify?

Comment: You're defining two classes at runtime when you instantiate `home_base`, but you never actually use those classes. It is rare in Python to actually declare nested classes like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should help guide you in the direction you should be going:

```
import math
import pygame


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Foondus v0.1')
    pygame.init()
    home = HomeBase(300, 300, screen)
    while True:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()


class HomeBase:

    def __init__(self, x, y, screen):
        self.x, self.y, self.screen = x, y, screen
        self.base_image = pygame.image.load('base.png')
        self.gun_image = pygame.image.load('gun.png')
        self.screen.blit(self.base_image, (self.x, self.y))
        self.screen.blit(self.gun_image, (self.x, self.y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, I see how the definition of a 'main' class could allow for multiple screens. Might I ask as to why the 'self.' is required before the screen.blit() function or does that relate to the function 'main()' that is calling it?

Comment: Also what is '__name__' ?

Comment: `self` is required so that the screen can be referred to in other `HomeBase` methods without having to pass the `screen` to those methods each time. \_\_name\_\_ is a global variable in every module that allows the module to know if it is being executed directly or imported.

Answer (score 0):

you wouldn't usually define a class inside the `__init__` method of another class. instead, I would do something along these lines:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, instance_classB):
        # here self is an instance of A and instance_classB an instance of B
        pass

class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # self is the newly created instance of B
        self._instance_classA = A(self)

# create an instance of B - calls B.__init__ on the new instance
b = B()
```

that way, you have instances of class `B` have a reference to an instance of class `A` in `self._instance_classA`, where each instance of class `A` has a backwards reference to the instance of class `B` it belongs to passed into the constructor.

Comment: I am entirely Thankful for your help, but honestly that is beyond my understanding currently...

Comment: @ChrisReal then this is what you should focus on - understanding the general case, and what `__init__` and `self` actually are is very important and the foundation for much much more.